# How do I log in to Ubuntu on a raspberry pi for initial setup after system installation?

Tags: boot, system-installation

I just booted into Ubuntu and got it turned on on my Raspberry Pi. When I did, it took me through a terminal screen then asked for a username and password in a black terminal looking environment. What is it and how do I get to the setup screen?

Comment: Which setup screen do you want? Are you talking about gui (Graphical User interface) ?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu? Is this Server or Desktop (GUI) version? Edit your question and add this info.

Comment: We need clear details! Avoid ambiguity and tell us the exact steps you are taking and tell us exactly what you see. If necessary, upload an image to imgur and link here.  Please use [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1376431/edit) to add details.  We also need to know what Raspberry Pi you have, what version of Ubuntu you installed, how you installed it, and what you mean by "set-up screen". The quality of help can only be as good as the quality of your inquiry. Make sure that we can understand all of the details and context.

Comment: The default username and password for Ubuntu Server if you flashed a "preinstalled" server image is `ubuntu` for both the username and password. Could this be what you mean? You will have to change the password to something more secure after the first time you log in.